Why does the force exerted on a vertical dam not depend on the width of a river?
I am probably looking at the wrong places but everything I can find starts with $p=\rho gh$ and not the why. So, why? Why can the same wall that holds the water in a $40\,\text{cm}$ high aquarium work as a river dam to hold water of that height?

"Why does the force exerted to a vertical dam not depend on the width of a river?" The pressure depends on the depth. The force depends on the pressure integrated over the area of the dam, so the force does depend on the width.

The problem is, this is not the question I wanted to ask :( it's a language oopsie. I probably need to ask a new one because editing this would make the answer nonsense: I wanted to ask floodwalls :/

Welp, then accept the best answer and move on to the new question.


Why does the force exerted to a vertical dam not depend on the width
of a river?

The total force does depend on the width. It is the force per unit area (pressure) that doesn't depend on the width.
Whether or not the structure is capable of resisting the total force depends on the strength of the means that supports the structure along its width.
Hope this helps.

There's more than one kind of dam. The majority of river dams are gravity dams. In a gravity dam, it's the weight of the dam, and nothing but the weight of the dam, that holds the water back—keeps the water from pushing the dam over or pushing parts of it out of the way.
The width of the dam plays no role in the calculation because the weight is distributed along the whole width of it exactly as the force of the water is distributed along the whole width of it. If dam A is twice as wide as dam B, and if both dams are the same height, then A must hold back twice the total force as B, but A also weighs twice as much.

The next most common kind of dam, the arch dam is built in deep, narrow canyons, where there are hard rock walls on both sides. The free-body diagram of an  arch dam looks similar to the free body diagram of an arch bridge, except the dam is like a bridge laying on its side. The load borne by a bridge is vertical, but the load borne by the dam is horizontal.
The calculations for how much material and how strong it must be depend very much on the width of the dam when you're designing an arch dam.
